# Sharing DLLs between multiple WCF services?

Tags: wcf

I have a MyComapny.Models project and a MyCompany.DataLayer project. I have about ten services: UserService, PurchaseOrderService, CustomerService, etc.. Each of the services has a reference to both .dlls. When I publish a service, it packages up the referenced .dlls and puts them in my server's IIS XService\bin\referencedDllNameHere.dll. That means that if I want to make a minor change to one of the .dll's, I have to re-publish all ten+ services (or copy the updated .dll in 10 places).

Is there a way to publish the service and have it look at a common location for the two referenced .dlls? This way, there is ONE single location where they would need to be updated. I could simply paste over them and viola. Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to reference shared copies I would use reflection to load/unload the .dlls at runtime inside your services. This would allow you to reference from a common location and you could change/updated the .dll files without having to rebuild your service code.